# Загрузка данных в record циклом из файла

Tags: delphi, pascal

Здравствуйте. Задача состоит в том, чтобы получить из файла строку, далее разбить полученную строку на подстроки или числа и каждую подстроку или число записать в record в свою ячейку. То есть, есть строка:

125%gikalo 25 kv 45%12%20%15%60

Вытаскиваем по очереди куски до %, а вот как загрузить их именно на свое место:
125 в driver.number, gikalo 25 kv 45 в driver.address и т.д.

```
...
    type
        driver = record
         number,timeFrom, timeTo, value, weight:integer;
         address:string;
        end;
    ...
    procedure TForm1.ck(Sender: TObject);
    var str:string;
        i:integer;
    begin
     AssignFile(drivers, 'drivers.txt');
     reset(drivers);
     while not EoF(drivers) do begin
      readln(drivers,str);
      while i:=1 to length(str) do begin
    //сохраняем кусочек строки до %

      end;
     end;
    end;
```

Есть идея переименовать названия ячеек рекорда в цифры начиная с 1, и при обработке циклом записывать в iую ячейку и наращивать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы не стал мучиться с for, и сделал бы просто через ExtractStrings:

```
procedure TForm1.ck(Sender: TObject);
var str:string;
    i:integer;
    Strings:TStrings;
begin
  Strings:=TStringList.Create;
  try
    AssignFile(drivers, 'drivers.txt');
    reset(drivers);
    while not EoF(drivers) do begin
      readln(drivers,str);
      ExtractStrings(['%'],[],PChar(str),Strings);
      driver.number:=StrToInt(Strings[0]);
      driver.address:=Strings[1];
      ...
    end;
  finally
    Strings.Free;
  end;
```

Это я упростил для примера. Конечно, нужно создать массив, состоящий из record типа driver:

```
type
  TDrivers: array of driver;
procedure TForm1.ck(Sender: TObject);
const
  MaxArr = 10;
var str:string;
    i:integer;
    Strings:TStrings;
    Drivers: TDrivers;
    Count: Integer;
begin
  Strings:=TStringList.Create;
  try
    AssignFile(drivers, 'drivers.txt');
    reset(drivers);
    i:=0;
    Count:=0;
    while not EoF(drivers) do begin
      readln(drivers,str);
      ExtractStrings(['%'],[],PChar(str),Strings);
      if i mod MaxArr=0 then begin
        Inc(Count,MaxArr);
        SetLength(Drivers,Count);
      end;
      Drivers[i].number:=StrToInt(Strings[0]);
      Drivers[i].address:=Strings[1];
      Inc(i);
      ...
    end;
  finally
    Strings.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Не работает, пишет Object or type class required.

Comment: Извиняюсь, все работает, спасибо большое.

Comment: Дважды извиняюсь, но не прокатит. Т.к. если файл будет состоять не из одной строки, то, к примеру, для второй строки первый элемент списка будет храниться в strings[6], а надо ноль. Каждый раз переменную наращивать не хочется)

Comment: Попробуй перед вызовом ExtractStrings обнулять Strings (Strings.Clear)